# Copy and Store LPTSTR in class causes crash

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to copy a LPTSTR and store that string as a member variable in an object. But my attempts to copy the LPTSTR seem to fail and when I go to access/print the value of the copied LPTSTR I get a program crash.

Is it possible to copy a LPTSTR and store it in my class below or is it better to just use a TCHAR*?

```
class Checkbox
{
   private:
      LPTSTR text;
      HWND hwnd;

   public:
      Checkbox(HWND nHwnd, LPTSTR nText)
      {
        lstrcpy(checkText, text); 
      }

      void print()
      {
        // Causes a crash
        MessageBox(hwnd, text, text, MB_OK);
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPTSTR is just a pointer. So, you need to take care to allocate memory before using it. So is the case with TCHAR*. Alternatively you could use wstring, if you have to worry about unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

You copy to an *uninitialized* pointer, which will overwrite some random area in memory. You need to allocate memory for the pointer first, and also remember to free the memory when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers have said, you need to allocate memory to "LPTSTR text" before you can use it.

Get the length of the string (strlen should do) you want to copy and then allocate the memory like this:

```
text = TCHAR[length];
```

You can declare a deconstructor for your class to delete the allocated memory when the program ends or the program leaves the scope of the class instance.

```
~CheckBox()
{
if (text)
delete[] text;
}
```

You should also create another constructor with no parameters that sets text to NULL;